# Why am not able to access my model class in Swift Project?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

**How to access my Model from ViewController and use the Model data to load in table view????**

Source Code [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/orb90e9o8u0y47l/AACuZml3Dp0ncyOpBaoAxMrga?dl=0)

My ViewController looks like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cclm: CountryCodeListModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(hello), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        readLocalJSONFile(forName: "countryList")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
    }
    
    @objc func hello()
     {
        print(cclm?.data?[0].flag)
     }

}
```

and my model class look like this

```
struct CountryCodeList : Decodable {
    var alpha2Code: String?
    var alpha3Code: String?
    var flag      : String?
    var name      : String?
    var code      : String?
}

public struct CountryCodeListModel : Decodable {
    var data      : [CountryCodeList]?
}

var cclm: CountryCodeListModel?


//Method to load json

func readLocalJSONFile(forName name: String) {
    do {
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json") {
            let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            if let countryCodeObject = parse(jsonData: data) {
                cclm = countryCodeObject
                print(cclm?.data?[1].alpha2Code ?? "")  //Printing Correct Value
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}



func parse(jsonData: Data) -> CountryCodeListModel?{
    var dataArray : [Dictionary<String,Any>] = [[:]]
    var country = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    var modelData = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    do {
        // make sure this JSON is in the format we expect
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            dataArray.removeAll()
            for item  in json["data"] as! [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
                country = item
                
                let url = URL(string: country["flag"] as? String ?? "")
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let fileName = url?.lastPathComponent // name of the image to be saved
                let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName ?? "")
                if let data = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0){
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: fileURL)
                        country["flag"] = fileURL.absoluteString
                        //print("file saved")
                        //urlAsString = fileURL.absoluteString
                    } catch {
                        print("error saving file:", error)
                    }
                }
                
                dataArray.append(country)
                country.removeAll()
                
                    
                
            }
            modelData["data"] = dataArray
            //print(modelData)
            let jsonData1 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: modelData, options: [])
            
            do {
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(CountryCodeListModel.self, from: jsonData1)
                
                    return decodedData
                } catch {
                    print("error: \(error)")
                }
            
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Problem statement:

Iam reading local json and take the url value of flag key and download corresponding images to local. Once i download then am taking the localpath and update in the dictionary and then create JSON object and update my model class.

Now, am trying to access my model class from ViewController like below

```
print(CountryCodeListModel?.data?[0].name) //check screenshot for error
 print(cclm?.data?[0].flag)                 // this prints nil always
```

Please check the error screenshots attached[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHnNA.png)

My JSON look like this

```
{
   "meta":{
      "success":true,
      "message":"Successfully retrieved country details",
      "code":"200"
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "alpha2Code":"AF",
         "alpha3Code":"AFG",
         "flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/countries/master/afg.png",
         "name":"Afghanistan",
         "code":"+93"
      },
      {
         "alpha2Code":"AX",
         "alpha3Code":"ALA",
         "flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/countries/master/ala.png",
         "name":"Aland Islands",
         "code":"+358"
      },
      {
         "alpha2Code":"AL",
         "alpha3Code":"ALB",
         "flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/countries/master/alb.png",
         "name":"Albania",
         "code":"+355"
      },
      {
         "alpha2Code":"DZ",
         "alpha3Code":"DZA",
         "flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/countries/master/dza.png",
         "name":"Algeria",
         "code":"+213"
      },
      {
         "alpha2Code":"AS",
         "alpha3Code":"ASM",
         "flag":"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevTides/countries/master/asm.png",
         "name":"American Samoa",
         "code":"+1684"
      }
]
}
```

Comment: `CountryCodeListModel` is a class. You can think of this as a blueprint. It defines properties `flag` and `name`... but it's just a blueprint. It's not an actual thing.

Comment: `cclm?.data?[0].flag` is the right way. But it's nil because you never initialized it (initializing is like creating an actual object from that blueprint. You need to do `cclm = CountryCodeListModel()`)

Comment: But, you are decoding from JSON. `if let countryCodeObject = parse(jsonData: data) { cclm = countryCodeObject }` will initialize `cclm`, but only if the `parse()` method doesn't return nil. It seems like this is returning nil... which means your JSON might have something wrong with it.

Comment: Why do you load  the same data from the bundle every 3 seconds? And why do you convert the data three times back and forth (with `JSONSerialization` and `JSONDecoder`)? That's pretty confusing.

Comment: @aheze  CountryCodeListModel is a Struct not a class.

Comment: @aheze my parse method returning data correctly, i can see that

Comment: @aheze am just testing by printing it in 3 seconds

Comment: @aheze in case if you want to check the source code https://www.dropbox.com/sh/orb90e9o8u0y47l/AACuZml3Dp0ncyOpBaoAxMrga?dl=0

Comment: Where does a guy named parse(jsonData: ) come from?

Comment: check the code attached

Comment: You are printing the values of two different properties and you are doing something confusing with the `flag` value in the `parse` method. And you are using too many unnecessary optionals. For example if the data is coming from the bundle you know precisely the content so you do know that all properties in `CountryCodeList` are clearly non-optional.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to decode something that doesn't exist.

```
print(CountryCodeListModel?.data?[0].name) //check screenshot for error
 print(cclm?.data?[0].flag)                 // this prints nil always
```

The above code states that you want:

1. the name of
2. the variable data at position 0 of
3. the struct `CountryCodeListModel`.

What you want to do is:

1. the name of
2. the variable at position 0 of
3. an INSTANCE of the struct `CountryCodeListModel`.

For example...

```
func readLocalJSONFile(forName name: String) {
    do {
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json") {
            let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
            if let countryCodeObject = parse(jsonData: data) {
                cclm = countryCodeObject
                print(cclm?.data?[1].alpha2Code ?? "")  //Printing Correct Value
                print(cclm?.data?[0].flag ?? "")
                print(countryCodeObject?.data[0].flag ?? "") // Same as the line above
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Unless you are trying to use a `static` variable (at which you would use `CountryCodeListModel.data`), you need to make sure you are actually using an instance of the structure or an object of a class to reference your properties.

**CAVEAT**

`CountryCodeListModel` is a structure. `CountryCodeListModel()` is an instance of the structure `CountryCodeListModel`. Since you can have multiple instances of a structure, you need to reference a specific structure when accessing data. Thus, `CountryCodeListModel.data` will not work and it needs to be `CountryCodeListModel().data`. In this case, you have `cclm.data`.

Comment: Have you ever read my question ??? am also able to get correct print result in readLocalJsonFile that i know. All am asking is why my print statement is always nil in viewController

Comment: All am trying to do is printing this in viewcontroller and trying to get correct value instead of nil. So you have any idea for that ?

Comment: I can see from my print statement that i have correctly added data to model inside readLocalJSONFile() and after that when i tried to print that it always nil. That is my exact problem

Comment: 1. I read your question. 2. I'm trying to help, don't be a d***. 3.  `print(CountryCodeListModel?.data?[0].name)` could not be farther from working unless you have a `static` variable which is not what you have. That is why `print(cclm?.data?[1].alpha2Code ?? "")` works and `print(CountryCodeListModel?.data?[0].name)` does not. Your `print(CountryCodeListModel?.data?[0].name)` is always nil because you are not referencing any data, as my answer states. You need to reference a SPECIFIC INSTANCE of your structure. e.g. `print(cclm?.data?[0].flag ?? "")`

Comment: I see one of your problems... You have `print(cclm?.data?[0].flag ?? "")`  inside your `hello` function that references your `cclm` inside of your class `ViewController`. Of course it won't have any data, you haven't set `cclm` equal to anything. So as it stands, `cclm` WILL BE something, but it is currently NOTHING. You'd have to do `cclm = SOMETHING` then it will have data.

Comment: You're thinking that the `cclm` inside your model class will assign the `cclm`  from your view class and that is 100% not the case. Try doing `print(cclm?.data?[0].flag ?? "")` where I put it in my answer above, within the model class.